# Bootstrap V4 Navbar not being responsive on smaller devices?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, styling

I'm currently trying to make my navbar responsive on smaller devices. However, as show in the screen shot, it's not properly shrinking. I've already tried making the `#footer` have `width:100%` and `width: 100vw` but those didn't work.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-light justify-content-center " id='footer'>
        <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
                <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class=class="nav-link d-flex flex-column">

                        <%= link_to teams_path do %>
                        <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-trophy" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M3 1h10c-.495 3.467-.5 10-5 10S3.495 4.467 3 1zm0 15a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h8a1 1 0 0 1 1 1H3zm2-1a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h4a1 1 0 0 1 1 1H5z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12.5 3a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-3 2a3 3 0 1 1 6 0 3 3 0 0 1-6 0zm-6-2a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-3 2a3 3 0 1 1 6 0 3 3 0 0 1-6 0z"/>
                            <path d="M7 10h2v4H7v-4z"/>
                            <path d="M10 11c0 .552-.895 1-2 1s-2-.448-2-1 .895-1 2-1 2 .448 2 1z"/>
                        </svg>
                        <% end %>
                        
                        <span class="nav-link px-5" href="#"><%= link_to 'Leaderboard', teams_path %></span>

                </a>
                </li>
                
                <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
                    
                    <a href="#" class=class="nav-link d-flex flex-column">      
                            <%= link_to teams_path do %>
                                <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-flag-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 1a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v13a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/>
                                                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.762 2.558C4.735 1.909 5.348 1.5 6.5 1.5c.653 0 1.139.325 1.495.562l.032.022c.391.26.646.416.973.416.168 0 .356-.042.587-.126a8.89 8.89 0 0 0 .593-.25c.058-.027.117-.053.18-.08.57-.255 1.278-.544 2.14-.544a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v6a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5c-.638 0-1.18.21-1.734.457l-.159.07c-.22.1-.453.205-.678.287A2.719 2.719 0 0 1 9 9.5c-.653 0-1.139-.325-1.495-.562l-.032-.022c-.391-.26-.646-.416-.973-.416-.833 0-1.218.246-2.223.916A.5.5 0 0 1 3.5 9V3a.5.5 0 0 1 .223-.416l.04-.026z"/>
                                </svg>
                              <% end %>
                              <span class="nav-link px-5" href="#"><%= link_to 'Challenges', challenges_path %></span>
            
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
                    <a href="#" class=class="nav-link d-flex flex-column">

                    <%= link_to teams_path do %>
                        <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-people-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm-5.784 6A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216zM4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5z"/>
                        </svg>

                    </a>
                    <% end %>
                    <span class="nav-link px-5" href="#"><%= link_to 'Team', teams_path %></span>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item d-flex flex-column">
                    <%= link_to teams_path do %>
                    <a href="#" class=class="nav-link d-flex flex-column">
                        <svg width="2em" height="2em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-card-image" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.5 3h-13a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h13a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z"/>
                            <path d="M10.648 7.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .577-.093L15.002 9.5V13h-14v-1l2.646-2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 .63-.062l2.66 1.773 3.71-3.71z"/>
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.502 7a1.5 1.5 0 1 0 0-3 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3z"/>
                        </svg>

                    </a>
                    <% end %>
                    <span class="nav-link px-5" href="#"><%= link_to 'Team', teams_path %></span>

                </li>       
            

            </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-brand {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .navbar #title{
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    ul.navbar-nav{
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #navlinks{
        display:none;
    }

    #footer{
        width:100vw;
    }
  
  }
```

Navbar on desktop

[image]

Navbar currently on smaller devices
[image]

Comment: Its overflowing because it can't fit everything (you have `px-5` on all nav-links and are not reducing that on smaller screens) and its a flex container which will not automatically wrap items unless you set `flex-wrap`. Yes you set it to 100% width, but they way its styled not everything will fit, you need responsive styling. What do you want to happen on smaller screens? SVG, text, and padding reduce in size? or have them start to stack?

Comment: @zgood on smaller screens, I would like both the text and SVGs to be reduced in size and evenly placed on the bottom. Would I have to remove the px-5?

Comment: You would have to write the responsive styles for that then  (reduce size of SVG and reduce font-size), like you did with the CSS sample above. You can do the same with the padding or use Bootstraps responsive helper classes... like this: `px-2 px-sm-5` instead of just `px-5`. Bootstrap is mobile first so it will have padding size of `px-2` on small screens, then when it hits the `sm` breakpoint it will be `px-5` on that breakpoint and above